# Table Group By - Tsql -

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, group-by

[alt text http://img187.imageshack.us/img187/8453/testhc3.png](http://img187.imageshack.us/img187/8453/testhc3.png)

[alt text http://img145.imageshack.us/img145/3306/test2bn4.png](http://img145.imageshack.us/img145/3306/test2bn4.png)

The first picture is my query. I need to obtain results in second picture.

```
select OrarioA, OrarioB, MAX(VW_DettaglioOrariLinee_FromAToB.IDOrario), dbo.VW_DettaglioOrariLinee_FromAToB.IDDettaglioOrarioA, dbo.VW_DettaglioOrariLinee_FromAToB.IDDettaglioOrarioB
FROM         dbo.VW_DettaglioOrariLinee_FromAToB INNER JOIN
                      Tb_Linee ON dbo.VW_DettaglioOrariLinee_FromAToB.IDRelA = Tb_Linee.IDRelA AND 
                      dbo.VW_DettaglioOrariLinee_FromAToB.IDRelB = Tb_Linee.IDRelB INNER JOIN
                      dbo.periodi ON dbo.VW_DettaglioOrariLinee_FromAToB.IDOrario = dbo.periodi.IDOrario INNER JOIN
                      dbo.relgiornisettimanaorarilinee ON dbo.VW_DettaglioOrariLinee_FromAToB.IDOrario = dbo.relgiornisettimanaorarilinee.IDOrario
```

This is my real query:

```
WITH Tb_Linee AS
(
    SELECT * FROM VW_rellineestazionamenti 
    WHERE 
    IDLINEA = @IDLINEA 
    AND 
    IDStazA = @IDStazA 
    AND
    IDStazB = @IDStazB 
    AND
    PosizioneA = @PosizioneA
    AND
    PosizioneB = @PosizioneB
)


select OrarioA, OrarioB, VW_DettaglioOrariLinee_FromAToB.IDOrario, dbo.VW_DettaglioOrariLinee_FromAToB.IDDettaglioOrarioA, dbo.VW_DettaglioOrariLinee_FromAToB.IDDettaglioOrarioB
FROM         dbo.VW_DettaglioOrariLinee_FromAToB INNER JOIN
                      Tb_Linee ON dbo.VW_DettaglioOrariLinee_FromAToB.IDRelA = Tb_Linee.IDRelA AND 
                      dbo.VW_DettaglioOrariLinee_FromAToB.IDRelB = Tb_Linee.IDRelB INNER JOIN
                      dbo.periodi ON dbo.VW_DettaglioOrariLinee_FromAToB.IDOrario = dbo.periodi.IDOrario INNER JOIN
                      dbo.relgiornisettimanaorarilinee ON dbo.VW_DettaglioOrariLinee_FromAToB.IDOrario = dbo.relgiornisettimanaorarilinee.IDOrario
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to partition by `OrarioA` only:

```
SELECT OrarioA, OrarioB, IDOrario, IDDettaglioOrarioA, IDDettaglioOrarioB
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrarioA ORDER BY OrarioB DESC, IDOrario DESC) AS rn
  FROM table
  ) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

, this will result in the resultset as on `picture 2`.

If you want to partition by `OrarioA` and `OrarioB`:

```
SELECT OrarioA, OrarioB, IDOrario, IDDettaglioOrarioA, IDDettaglioOrarioB
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrarioA, OrarioB ORDER BY IDOrario DESC) AS rn
  FROM table
  ) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

, but this won't filter out the first row in your resultset.

Comment: Only a question, If I want to partition by OrarioA And OrarioB. What Have I to do? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

From the data you explained in your screenshots, I understand it as you need the id fields for the most highest IDOrario grouped by OrarioA and OrarioB?

```
SELECT IDDettaglioOrarioA, IDDettaglioOrarioB
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY
OrarioA, OrarioB
ORDER BY IDOrario DESC
```

If you need to select more columns, select any more at will.